# Mean Value Theorem and turning points for a periodic function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be a function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ which is differentiable at every point, and such that $f (x + 1) = f (x)$ for every $x$. Prove that there exist at least $2$ points in $[0, 1]$ where the derivative of $f$ equals zero.

I understand how to prove there is one point, by applying the mean value theorem to $0$ and $1$. How do you prove there must be at least one more? I can see it from a picture but can't prove it formally.

Comment: If $f'(0)=0,$ then periodicity gives $f'(1)=0$ and you're done. Consider what happens if $f'(0)>0.$ Maybe think about where $f$ assumes max/min values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am assuming that $f$ is not constant.

that the function has one point in $(0, 1)$ at which $f' = 0$ is easier with the help of the mean value theorem applied to $f$ on $[0,1]$

to show that it must have at least one more in $[0,1],$ we can argue by contradiction.  slog, we can assume that $f'(0) = \neq 0, f'(1) \neq 0.$ we also can assume that $f(0) \ge 0,$ if not consider $-f.$ we know that $f$ has a local extremum in $(0,1).$ if that is the only one then you can see that $f'(0)f'(1) < 0$ contradicting the fact that $f'(1) = f'(0).$ therefore $f$ must have at least two extremum points in $(0,1).$

Answer (score 0):

A function on a compact set has a minimum and a maximum; if it's smooth, its derivative is zero at both points, or they're endpoints of the interval.

Case 1: constant function. Conclusion is trivial.

Case 2: Nonconstant:

For your function, find the first min on the interval $[0, 1]$; call it $a$. Then find the next max and call that $b$. We know that $a \ne b$ and $b - a < 1$ by periodicity.   Let $c = (a + b)/2$ and look at the interval $[c-1/2, c + 1/2]$. The max and min on that interval occur at $a$ and $b$, which are interior points, so the derivatives at those points are zero. Now look at $a \bmod 1$ and $b \bmod 1$ and you're done.